# EF6 nested collection count (without fetching) with/without automapper

Tags: entity-framework-6

According to [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#using-query-to-count-related-entities-without-loading-them) there is a neat way to count nested collection elements without actually fetching them. Great. But the example is for a single item.

Of course, I could iterate and do this in post-processing. But that's not neat.

And here could something like Automapper come into play. It has a `ProjectTo` extension for `IQueryable` which [can be parameterized](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization) (in quite a weird way imho).

Well, I can't get it working. Let's say I have a `Client` entity that has associated `Device` entities, and I want to set the `DeviceCount` property of the target.

By combining the examples from the two sources, something like this could work:

```
_configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
       {
                    SMPContext ctx = null; ///why not an extra property in conf? 
                    cfg.CreateProjection<Client, Models.ViewModels.Client>()
                        .ForMember(d => d.DeviceCount, conf => conf.MapFrom(s => ctx.Entry(s).Collection(c => c.Devices).Query().Count()));
                });
        }

...
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var res = await 
                    _context
                    .Clients.ProjectTo<SMP.Models.ViewModels.Client>(_configuration, new { ctx = _context })
                .ToListAsync();
...
```

I was experimenting with this too:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateProjection<Client, Models.ViewModels.Client>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.DeviceCount, conf => conf.MapFrom(s => _context.Entry(s).Collection(c => c.Devices).Query().Count()));
            });

            var res = await 
                    _context
                    .Clients.ProjectTo<SMP.Models.ViewModels.Client>(configuration)
                .ToListAsync();
 ...
```

Either way, I get such an exception, which is quite understandable:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> '___context_0.Entry(NavigationTreeExpression Value:
> EntityReference: Client Expression: c).Collection(c =>
> c.Devices).Query() .Count()' could not be translated.

I have tried using `Map` instead of `ProjectTo`, but no luck either, as  `IMapper.Map().AfterMap` passes the entire enumerable as parameter instead of per item.

Is there any neat solution?

Comment: You need FK properties. But you can try it without AM, see what's posssible, and then you can refactor that to `ProjectTo`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have them. `Include` works as expected. I might have found a neat solution though. See my solution in a few moments.

Comment: Then you should use those :) Not this hack you have here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a simple and neat solution with AutoMapper after all: `CreateProjection` is smart enough to create a performant SQL mapping in such a case:

```
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(config => 
        config.CreateProjection<SMP.Models.DataModels.Client, SMP.Models.ViewModels.Client>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DeviceCount, o=> o.MapFrom(s => s.Devices.Count))
        );
```

Using it is simple as well:

```
var res = await _context.Clients
                .ProjectTo<Models.ViewModels.Client>(_mapper/*injected IMapper*/.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
```

The generated SQL query looks like this:
[image]

Comment: If you rename `DeviceCount` to `DevicesCount`, you don't need the `MapFrom`.